# AttributeError when opening locked zip file in Python

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to check the password of zip file is correct using a function:

```
import zipfile

def isCorrectPassword(zip_file, password):
    try:
        zip_file.extractall(pwd=bytes(password,'utf-8'))
        print("Success")
        return True
    except:
        print("Fail")
        return False
```

However, when I run this, it returns False. I know for sure the password is correct.

I've tried re-running this script with just this:

```
zip_file.extractall(pwd=bytes(password,'utf-8'))
```

including all necessary variables, but it still doesn't work - it produces this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extractall'

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Based on the error you are getting, `zip_file` is a string. How are you calling  `isCorrectPassword`?

Comment: Are you by any chance supplying this method with the path to the zip file instead of a ZipFile instance?

Comment: I'm using it in an if statement

Comment: I think so - do you mean zip_file = "example.zip"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your zip_file variable is a string and therefore extract_all cannot be called on it.  Try this:

```
def isCorrectPassword(zip_file, password):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file) as file:
            file.extractall(pwd=bytes(password,'utf-8'))
        print("Success")
        return True
    except:
        print("Fail")
        return False
```